# How do I fix TPM error 256?

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, 17.10, tpm

This happened when I attempted to upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04.

I receive this error during boot, and my Ubuntu that I've had a few months running without issue twice (not counting during the upgrade) randomly reset to select user and login screen but let me back into my desktop no problem.

During the unpacking part of the update it did this and hung in a select user, type password loop not letting me into the desktop. I turned my computer off twice and on the third try I get a consistent error `256` after selecting Ubuntu from the GRUB menu. My system was at full battery during all these random resets.

How do I fix my system without losing my files? It was only 1/10 or 1/20th unpacked on the update bar. I'm on an Asus with Intel processor/graphics card.

Comment: I just got A PIC metformin install handler for fixed event - power button (2) disabling (20170531\event-246

Comment: I was updating from 17.10 to 18.04 But I can still use the grub and windows mode i assume, it's just ubuntu that will not start. Why do I need the Asus plate? I have only ever used 17.1 and it's never given me issue until today. Also I've had Ubuntu for months, since I installed it from CD.

Comment: "Why do I need the Asus plate?" Because it will enable us to direct you to the manual for your PC, and to the BIOS Setup section you need to resolve this.

Comment: I opened the BIOS on N150ZU lenovo, but the /security/ TPM option was already desabled, and I still got the error message at boot up attempting the self test

Answer (score 4):

Please go into your BIOS/Setup, find something like Security, then looks for a Chip or TPM item; change the setting to disabled and that should clear the Trusted Platform Module issue.

Comment: I opened Bios setup, but there was no tpm setting to turn on or off, so where is it? Also I know nothing of tpm i just typed what was on my computer screen

Comment: When you have an update to a question, please go to the question, click on the grey [edit] link above and to the left, and put the new findings into the original question. Also, please advise the model number of your Asus PC from the serial number plate on its underside, and the version of the BIOS it uses from the BIOS/UEFI/Firmware settings. Without finding that, we can't see which version of the BIOS you should be using.